# How to do if statement and assignment in configparser config file?

Tags: python, configparser

I want to use if statement and variable assignment in my config file.  I have tried but it seems impossible.  Right now the "begin" value is read in and the application runs it using python system call.  So it will be system(
if %(USER_MODE)s=="ADMIN"; then PASSWD: %(ADMIN_PASSWD)s else PASSWD: %(ROOT_PASSWD)s; fi).

config file:

```
[DEFAULT]
ADMIN_PASSWD: ADMIN
ROOT_PASSWD: ROOT
[setup:password]
begin: if %(USER_MODE)s=="ADMIN"; then PASSWD: %(ADMIN_PASSWD)s else PASSWD: %(ROOT_PASSWD)s; fi
end: echo %(PASSWD)s
```

Comment: Typically, the logic goes inside your application, not in the config file.

Comment: The requirement that we were given is to minimize touching existing code due to the big test matrix.  I have tried various ways but it seems impossible, that is why I am asking for ideas here :)

Comment: I would consider this a minimal exercise to touch existing code, since a config file doesn't contain any way to execute or determine logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `if` statement or manipulate environment variables in a ConfigParser config file.

You haven't provided what the code looks like in the "big test matrix".

Here is one scenario where you could provide a default password that is used if one is not present for a user.

Config file 'pwd.ini':

```
[DEFAULT]
password = root_password123

[admin]
password = admin_password123
email = admin@xyz.com

[user1]
email = user1@xyz.com
```

`user1` does not have a `password` entry. So configparser will supply a the default value (root_password123):

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('pwd.ini')

print(config['admin']['password'])
print(config['user1']['password'])
```

gives

```
admin_password123
root_password123
```